# Would increasing the window size of an observation plane, like a camera, increase resolution?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, fourier-transform

I have a diffraction pattern emanating from a source and incident upon an observation plane. If I increase the size of the observation plane, it would increase the number of spatial frequencies in the tangential direction hitting the plane.

However, I don't intuitively understand how this is possible. How can increasing the observation plane of something, when it already fits the entire image, further increase its resolution?

Answer (score 0):

No, if the size of the observation plane is increased, one would not increase the spatial frequencies in that plane (Unless you consider the image in that plane as the spectrum, since it is in the far field. I'm going to assume this is not the case), however, since the size of the resolvable point in that plane stays fixed, one would get more of those points if one increases the size of that plane. To increase the resolution in that plane (to increase the number of spatial frequencies and thus reduse the size of the resolvable points), one would need to increase the size of the aperture of the Fourier plane prior to the observation plane. Perhaps, that aperture would be the diameter of the lens that images the light onto the observation plane.